# This will register the COM out of proc server

Tags: c#, quickbooks

I am trying to develop a C# Wrapper for QuickBooks which will add a new menu in QuickBooks under Reports menu. While clicking that need to invoke a windows application.

I have tried this example https://github.com/IntuitDeveloper/QBXML_SDK13_Samples/tree/master/qbdt/c-sharp/qbXML/SubscribeAndHandleQBEvent_vs03

But I am getting error at this command "SubscribeAndHandleQBEvent.exe  -d"

Error: Error while registering for QB events - Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {45F5708E-3B43-4FA8-BE7E-A5F1849214CB} failed due to the following error: 80040154.

I am not sure what I am missing, if you have any idea on this please share.

Comment: Did you run *SubscribeAndHandleQBEvent.exe  -regserver* as your first action?

Comment: Hi,Yes I have run SubscribeAndHandleQBEvent.exe -regserver as my first action.

Comment: Try running *SubscribeAndHandleQBEvent.exe -regserver* as Administrator.